# some time button click event is being fired twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems that sometimes (but not always) my button click event is being fired twice. The fact that it seems to happen sometimes but not always is really puzzling me. i already try button visible false or disable functionality. please help. Here is my button :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" style="background-color:#e3e6ea; padding:5px; color:#000000; font-weight:bold;"  ValidationGroup="Validate" />
```

Comment: Please add relevant code, what button, which button? WPF? Windows Forms? No one can help without complete detailed code.

Comment: you'll need to narrow it down a bit. Just one bit of button markup doesn't tell us anything about why this could happen. Does Javascript trigger an additional postback somehow? Does something else in the code-behind call the btnSubmit_Click method? You'll have to experiment and watch for the different circumstances which cause this apparent behaviour. It will be specific to the rest of your application somehow, some environmental situation - combination of variables, code flow or whatever. Unfortunately you're really the only one who can sit and work through the test cases to find the source

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OnClientClick` and `UseSubmitBehavior` properties of the button control  you can prevent the double click , change your `asp.net` code as follows :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
Text="Submit" 
OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" 
OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;"
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
style="background-color:#e3e6ea; 
padding:5px; 
color:#000000; font-weight:bold;"  ValidationGroup="Validate" />
```

You need to add `OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;"` and `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` to your button control

Answer (score -2):

i think you have used "btnSubmit_Click" event twice in your code, please check your code ,i hope your problem will solve.